# receber dois valores autocomplete e repassar para < input tipe='hidden' >

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, autocompletar

como faço para repassar um valor `'ID - valor'` de um `autocomplete jquey` e mostrar somente o `'valor'` no campo `input` e passar o `'ID'` para outro `input` tipo `hidden`.

> PHP

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
$return_arr = array();

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,nome FROM produtos WHERE nome LIKE :term ");
    $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $return_arr[] =  $row['id'].' - '.$row['nome'] ;
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

> JS

```
$(".produto").autocomplete({
    source: "../../../centrolimp/assets/php/busca_produtos.php",
    minLength: 2
});


// Essa parte que insiro as linhas na tabela ...

contador++;


    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td class="contador valor_total" >' + contador + '</td>';
    cols += '<td><label text-align="center"><input type="text" name="produto' + contador + '" class="produto" /></label></td>';
    cols += '<td><label text-align="center"><input type="text" name="qtd' + contador + '"     class="qtd spinner" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" /></label></td>';
    cols += '<td><label text-align="center"><input type="text" name="preco' + contador + '"   class="preco"  align="center" /></label></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2 total">R$ 0.00</td>';
    cols += '<td><a class="deleteLinha"> Excluir </a></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
```

Já estou recebendo o valor certinho, só preciso dividir este resultado agora.

Comment: No autocomplete tem uma propriedade pra isso.  `$( ".produto" ).autocomplete({
          source: "../../../centrolimp/assets/php/busca_produtos.php",
          minLength: 2,
          select: function( event, ui ) {
              "Selecionado: " + ui.item.value + ", Id: " + ui.item.id :
           }
        }); `

Comment: Não ta recebendo o valor ... via console.log(ui.item.value);

Comment: Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258268

Comment: Se usar isso `$return_arr[] =  json_encode(array("id" => $row['id'], "valor" => $row['nome']));` ou `$return_arr[] =  array("id" => $row['id'], "valor" => $row['nome']);` retorna um json em vez de string?

Comment: não estou conseguindo impletentar @wmsouza ... a ideia segui esta mesmo .... porem quero que o 'valor' esteje no input próprio e o ID em outro input para poder trata-lo em meu form.

Comment: e esta gerando um erro tbm ... 

Uncaught Error: no such method 'instance' for autocomplete widget instance

Comment: Pronto, editado .... tinha me esquecido de colocar esta parte !!

Comment: É só fazer como o @GuilhermeCostamilam falou, alterar `$return_arr[] =  $row['id'].' - '.$row['nome'] ;` para `$return_arr[] = array("id" => $row['id'], "value" => $row['nome']);`

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar ..... agora um grande problema é que ele só esta funcionando no primeiro input da coluna, pois estes inputs são dinamicos e o auto complete é chamado pela classe ... como corrigir isso ??

Comment: O problema pra fazer funcionar tenh ode explicar .... estava dando incopatibilidade da versao  do jquery ui

Comment: Conseguiu resolver ? Como é a estrutura *HTML* ? Os campos que diz, é o de pesquisar e o id?

Comment: ainda nao, inseri a parte do codigo que inseri as linhas na tabela dinamicamente.

Comment: oi amigos, voces tentaram retornar os dois valores ?? ainda to garrado nisso .